# spl_autoload_register and namespace errors

Tags: php, autoload

For some reason I am having an issue with spl_autoload_register with my namespace in a class file. If I include the class the normal way without spl_autoload_register it works just fine. Soon as I try to use spl_autoload_register it stops working and php throws an error.

Here are my test files:
info.php

```
<?php

include '../class/soapConn.php';

spl_autoload_register(
  function ($class) {
    include '../class/' . $class . '.php';
  }
);
// include '../class/lists.php'; //This works with the name space!

if (isset($_GET["data"]) && $_GET["data"] == "test") {
  $schoolsList = new \DBviewer\lists($client); //Can't find the class?
  $array=[];
  $array = $schoolsList->getSchools();

  echo json_encode($array);

}
```

class file:
lists.php

```
<?php
namespace DBviewer;

include '../class/soapConn.php';

class lists {

  function __construct($client) {
    $this->client=$client;
  }

  function getSchools() {
    //random stuff here

    return $array;
  }
}
```

Any idea why the autoload is causing me problems? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The class you're trying to load is called `\DBviewer\lists`. Do you have a file called `../class/DBviewer\lists.php`? because that is what your autoloader code is looking for

Comment: I have a file called ../class/lists.php. "DBviewer" is the namespace name in that class file. The problem is that spl_autoload_register is trying to look for the file /DBviewer\lists.php which doesn't exist. And if I try using the "use DBviewer\lists" before I create the object, it doesn't work since the class wasn't loaded yet. What is a creative solution for this?

Comment: You need to modify your autoload function to strip off the namespace then, though that rather eliminates the point of namespaces, you'd be better restructuring your folder tree to reflect the namespacing

Comment: How does that work when you specify a namespace with a backslash? Example DBviewer\lists. Folder structure is forward slashes? Just do a replace when calling it?

Comment: Take a look at the sample PSR-4 (namespaced) autoloader - https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md .... you don't need the mapped file part, but the rest of the code is appropriate